# How to create a weblink to open a osx desktop application?

Tags: macos, web-applications

I was wondering is it possible to create a web link so that when a user click's on it, it will open up a OSX application - 
How could I make like in terminal - open myapp.app

Or am I violating some OSX rule?

Comment: Answer below is correct - you will have seen this technique in action when you click on an iTMS link on the web and it passes it through to iTunes, external media players, or if you force PDFs to always open externally.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open your app, one way is to make your app handle a URL scheme, say `x-my-app-scheme://`. This can be done following the methods described in [this Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-BBCIDFHG). You also need to set `CFBundleURLTypes` in your `Info.plist`, as described there.
Then in your web page, make an `href` to `x-my-app-scheme://foo`.

You can't open an arbitrary app from a link in a web site. That would be a grave security hole; consider using that behavior from a Javascript.

Comment: Although that security hole has happened in the past (wasn't there some issue involving 'file' links where you could run arbitrary apps by making a good guess about the users file system. Fixed by deprecating file links from remote servers).

Comment: In fact custom URL schemes also caused security holes in the past, when the URL is inordinately expressive. One example was the help viewer; its custom scheme allowed one to execute arbitrary Applescript. Ugh!

Comment: Is there a Windows equivalent of this?

Comment: Same here, I'm interested in doing the same kind of links from web app to desktop app, on Windows. Say I have an app and I want it to have a link that opens up a blank document in Word. How can one achieve such things ?